# HTML Partials with Webpack

Tags: webpack, ejs, webpack-dev-server, partials

I have a rather long HTML file. I would like to split it up into one base file and multiple smaller files that I can then include into said base file. I am using Webpack, so I am thinking there must be a way to do this at build time.

I have looked around, tried [ejs-easy-loader](https://github.com/snoleo/ejs-easy-loader), but couldn't get it to work. I am not really sure what the best approach is, or if there is a better alternative.

Conceptually, I want to do this:

**Project structure**

```
index.html
partials
- partial-1.html
- partial-2.html
- ...
- partial-9.html
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>

Base file content

<!-- Include partial-1.html -->
<!-- Include partial-2.html -->
<!-- ... -->
<!-- Include partial-9.html -->

More base file content

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach in my opinion is to address it in webpack build process, which means to hook into the compiler and construct the main.html from your partial ones.

You can create a simple plugin that does this:

```
const fs = require("fs");

class BuildHtml {
    constructor(partialHtmls) {
        this.partialHtmls = partialHtmls;
    }
    apply(compiler) {
        // Called before emitting assets to dist folder.
        compiler.hooks.emit.tap('BuildHtml', (compilation) => {
            // Construct main html content from partial htmls.
            let mainHtmlContent = "<html><body>" + this.partialHtmls.join("") + "</body></html>"

            // '/dist/index.html' - should be the index.html output path if you use HtmlWebpackPlugin.
            fs.writeFileSync('/dist/index.html', mainHtmlContent);

            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

and consume your plugin in webpack configuration:

```
plugins: [
    BuildHtml
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding html-loader as a devDependency

Then (assuming webpack 5)

```
<body>

Base file content

<!-- Include partial-1.html -->
<%= require('html-loader!./partials/partial1.html').default %>

<!-- Include partial-2.html -->
<!-- ... -->
<!-- Include partial-9.html -->

More base file content

</body>
</html>
```